# isomorphic abelian varieties

Tags: abelian-varieties

Let $A$ and $B$ be isogenous abelian varieties defined over a field $k$.

Suppose $A(L)\cong B(L)$ for all finite extensions $L$ of $k$. Does this imply that $A\cong B$?

It would be different if we do not suppose $A$ and $B$ isogenous?

Comment: What happens when $k$ equals $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Not with complete local fields e.g. Tate curves over a p-adic field with same valuations of j invariants

Comment: $k$ is itself a finite extension of $k$

Comment: Perhaps you want to ask: Let $f: A \to B$ be a $k$-isogeny. If $f$ induces an isomorphism on $L$-valued points for all $L/k$ finite, is $f$ an isomorphism?

Comment: No, over a finite field $k$, there are elliptic curves $E,E'$ with isomorphic group of points over every finite extension of $k$, but $E$ is not isomorphic to $E'$ (it has to be isogenous by Tate theorem though). See the appendix in the 2001 paper "Group Structure of Elliptic Curves over Finite Fields" by Christian Wittmann. I don't know if this addresses the above (very good) comment.